# debian wheezy requiring libc6 >= 2.14

Tags: debian-wheezy, dependencies, libc6

Yesterday I tried to upgrade my debian wheezy to jessie version and it was unsuccessful - server does not boot anymore. I connect to shell, tried to reverse upgrade, but unfortunately, made everything even worse. Now I am sitting with bunch of packages that requires lib6 >= 2.14 and can't run apt-get.

What do You guys suggest me to do? I do not want to format and clean install, because there are a lot of important files there and I can not backup them properly (server is remote, 500gb~ of files). Tried to resize my main partition, to install fresh copy of debian alongside but after 4 hours of run - it failed, fortunately files is OK.

Also tried to run apt-get -f install with LD_LIBRARY_PATH, where libc6 newest version sit, got error " dpkg undefined symbol: setexecfilecon".